# Are there any errors in my summary of stationarity? and some more questions.

Tags: correlation, stationary-processes

I've posted questions about stationarity, but I cannot get answers satisfying me because of my vague question. Thus, I read more times about definitions about stationarity, summed them up, and brought out distinctly what I was concerning. I extremely and hopefully desire someone to get rid of my misconception and curiosities. I hope you to understand what my questions exactly are because I spend a large amount of time translating into English (, even if there are many grammatical errors).

---

### $1^{st}$ question: Are there any errors in my summary?

---

A random process is said to be ***first-order stationary*** if it satisfies the following equation:$$\forall \tau\in\mathbb{R}, \quad f_X(x_{t_1}) = f_X(x_{t_1+\tau})$$
, which means that expected value of process is independent of any time shift. Therefore, $E\left[X(t)\right]$ is constant.

---

Next, a random process is said to be ***second-order stationary*** or ***strict-sense stationary (SSS)***  if it satisfies the following equation:$$\forall \tau\in\mathbb{R}, \quad f_X(x_{t_1}, x_{t_2}) = f_X(x_{t_1+\tau}, x_{t_2+\tau})$$
, which means that the process depends only on the time difference. Therefore, $R_X(t_1, t_2)=R_X(t_1-t_2)=R_X(\tau)$, where $\tau$ is the time difference between $t_1$ and $t_2$.

---

In addition, a random process is said to be ***wide-sense stationary (WSS)*** if it satisfies the following two equations:
\begin{align}
&1. \quad E\left[X(t)\right] = k, \quad \text{where } k \text{ is constant}\\
&2. \quad R_X(t_1, t_2)=R_X(t_1-t_2)=R_X(\tau), \quad \text{where } \tau \text{ is } t_1-t_2
\end{align}

Note that a second-order stationary (or SSS) process will always be WSS; however, the reverse will not always hold true.

---

### $2^{nd}$ question: In SSS section, how come $R_X(t_1, t_2)$ becomes $R_X(\tau)$?

I tried to prove that $R_X(t_1, t_2)$ becomes $R_X(\tau)$. I think it's almost done but I do not agree with the last equality. How come two domains change into one domain? By verbal expression, which is less logical than mathematical expression, I agree with that it could be because it just depends only on $\tau$. However, I want to get to agree this from thorough mathematical expression.

\begin{align}
R_X(t_1, t_2) = E\left[X(t_1)X(t_2)\right] &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{xy f_{X_{t_1},X_{t_2}}(x, y)}dxdy\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{xy f_{X_{t_1-t_2},X_{0}}(x, y)}dxdy\\
&= E\left[X(t_1-t_2)X(0)\right] = R_X(t_1-t_2, 0) \stackrel{?}{=} R_X(\tau)
\end{align}

---

### $3^{rd}$ question: a process is SSS [image: arrow] the process is WSS

From my summary (originally from websites, textbooks and so on), it seems to me that **the necessary conditions of WSS** requires to satisfy simultaneously **the necessary condition of first-order stationrity** and **one of second-order stationarity(SSS)**. If my view is correct, WSS will always be SSS, the reverse will not always hold true, isn't it?

[image: diagram]

---

Comment: The very first definition is already wrong. Do you read the comments on your questions or do you consider that the people posting them should be made to feel they count for nothing?

Comment: @Did sorry, but I am reading all comments on my questions. Also, I don't want people to feel bad. Can I ask why the first definition is wrong? [Here][1] said the definition of first-order stationary.




  [1]: https://www.classle.net/#!/classle/book/stationary-process/

Comment: Terrible source. Who wrote this?

Comment: @Did Oh my god!! I studied with wrong sources? I found this by google search. Since this source is easy to read, I studied with this source. T.T I have to study again with other source. Hah!! so sad.

Comment: And [the WP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process) your other question seems to be based upon  is written incompetently as well... [This other link](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter10/10_1_4_stationary_processes.php) seems more serious.

Comment: @Did Very thank you. I am going to read carefully the website you linked.

Comment: @Did The website you linked is really nice. Explanation is really well and written English is very formal and readable. So very excellent for me who is not good at English. Thank you very much. This link is helpful above everything else.